# Wrapping an entire form in array on PHP POST

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, post

I am trying to wrap an entire form in an array. Currently looks like:

```
<div class="round">
    <input name="points">
    <input name="player1[]">
    <input name="player2[]">
</div>
```

The entire form/div can be duplicated, so, ideally, I would have an output that could be spit out as

```
round[0][points]
round[0][player1[0,1,2]]
round[0][player2[0,1,2]]
```

It needs to be dynamic, so simply adding round[0] as static text before everything won't work.

I have tried to wrap all of it in a , tried fieldset, but everything fails or spits out a terrible order of items.

Any ideas?

**Edit to clarify desired output:**
After all is said and done, I want this to be dynamic, hence the need for arrays within arrays. The output, after duplication, could be:

```
round[0][points]
round[0][player1[0,1,2]]
round[0][player2[0,1,2]]

round[1][points]
round[1][player1[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
round[1][player2[0,1,2,3,4,5]]

round[2][points]
round[2][player1[0,1]]
round[2][player2[0,1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're over thinking it simply add brackets after points like this:

```
<input name="points[]">
<input name="player1[]">
<input name="player2[]">
```

When you go to process in it php just use a foreach loop:

```
$player1 = $_POST['player1'];
$player2 = $_POST['player2'];
foreach($_POST['points'] as $i => $points){
   echo $points." ".$player1[$i]." ".$player2[$i];
}
```

Which should give you the results:

```
points[0] player1[0] player2[0]
points[1] player1[1] player2[1]
etc.
```

This should work (if I understand the question correctly).

**EDIT:**

Okay so I'm assuming the player1 & player2 input values are comma separated lists. If they are we just have to make an adjustment in the php:

```
$player1 = $_POST['player1'];
$player2 = $_POST['player2'];
foreach($_POST['points'] as $i => $points){
   echo "Round ".$i.": "$points;
   echo "Team 1";
   $team1 = explode(",", $player1[$i]);
   foreach($team1 as $i => $player){
      echo "Player ".$i.": ".$player;
   }
   echo "Team 2";
   $team2 = explode(",", $player2[$i]);
   foreach($team2 as $i => $player){
      echo "Player ".$i.": ".$player;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks isshakes. I have that down, but I need to duplicate all of it. So, once duplicated, it would come out as:

    round[0][points]
    round[0][player1[0,1,2]]
    round[0][player2[0,1,2]]

    round[1][points]
    round[1][player1[0,1,2]]
    round[1][player2[0,1,2]]

The points are not an array. The players are. Perhaps I should have asked this instead: how do I create an array within an array to submit via PHP.

I hope this clarifies and would love any insight you have.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "player1[0, 1, 2]" are there multiple player1s?

Comment: Yes. I tried to clarify a little above.

Each "player1" would be it's own array (maybe I should name it "team").

Comment: Okay are the player inputs comma separated?

Comment: They are inputs, and after they are dumped into the POST array, to keep them seperate in my database table, yes, I implode them with commas. The 0,1,2 are meant to represent values. 0 could equal "John", 1 could be "Smith", etc.

Comment: That design makes everything more complicated than it should.

Comment: I'm open to other suggestions, devJunk. If not what I am doing, what should it be?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: this gets the "player" array into the "round" array, now I just have to figure out how to auto-increment the round[] like I want to:

```
 <input name="_round[0][_player1][]">
```

But I think I could just use a counter for that... despite how much I hate counters.